# How to initialise an instance of 'Store' without it being a property of another view/object

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates

I'm refactoring some code where I had previously had my StoreKit code within a UIViewController (it was pointed out to me that this was bad practice).

So I will be putting all my StoreKit code into a class called Store (responsible for retrieving in-app-purchase information and processing payments etc). I then have a view controller which loads and displays details from the store (e.g. price etc).

I want to use the delegate pattern to update the viewcontroller but my question is where/how do I instantiate my Store object? The best would be for it to start at app launch (but it doesn't make sense for it to be a property of any UIViewController) - whats the best way to create this object?

Comment: I waited almost a day because my take may not be correct. I created an `extension` to a subclassed `UIViewController` for three StoreKit items: `SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. Sure, two of these are delegates, but one of those delegates *is* a view controller. My take? The only thing wrong with having your StoreKit code "within" a UIViewController is - reusable code, and/or a bloated UIViewController. Let me explain in a second comment.

Comment: (1) If all you care about is a bloated UIViewController, separate the SK code via an extension. Throw it into a second file, and you're done. (2) Reusable code. That was ultimately my issue - I had a non-consumable IAP and needed a good way to "restore purchases". With code spread across at least two view controllers (one for my edit view, one for restoring purchases) I moved everything I could into a *separate* "info" view controller, calling what was needed in the edit controller via that. I would "push back" some to whomever pointed out this "bad practice" for help on the specifics.

Comment: Thanks, my reason is to avoid the situation where someone loads the UIView for my store which initiates the request for products from Apple, then presses back. Then by the time the response comes back, the object that requested it (the UIView) no longer exists which seems to cause the app to quit.